# What are the hearts for in Kid Icarus Myths and Monsters?

Tags: kid-icarus-myths-monsters

I thought that the hearts were health related, but I am not entirely sure. I collect quite a few of them, and don't seem to have more health - either that, or I am just doing really, really badly.

Are the hearts health, or do they have some other purpose?

Answer (score 3):

[Hearts are currency](http://www.negativeworld.org/article.php?id=7640&pagenumber=1#.UAogyyPcj7g) and used for buying items such as potions, barrels etc. from sellers or black marketers.